# Install Windows Server 2012 R2 in qemu VM

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, windows-server-2012, qemu

I'm trying to install Windows Server 2012 R2, but right after loading Windows files I'm getting:

```
Your PC needs to restart. Please hold down the power button. Error Code: 0x0000005D
```

My command is:

```
qemu-system-x86_64.exe -L . -m 2048 -boot d -hda coeess_virtual.img -cdrom en_windows_server_2012_r2_x64_dvd_2707946.iso
```

Comment: Having the same trouble, did you find a solution? The answer below is not a solution.The reason I switch to qemu is because I do NOT have VT and VirtualBox cannot do 64 bit guests. qemu emulates the complete PC so there should be no "excuse"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify a supported x64 CPU. Who knows what QEMU defaults to.

Something like this (requires KVM):

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu host -m 2048 -boot d -hda coeess_virtual.img -cdrom en_windows_server_2012_r2_x64_dvd_2707946.iso
```

Or this (doesn’t require KVM):

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu Nehalem -m 2048 -boot d -hda coeess_virtual.img -cdrom en_windows_server_2012_r2_x64_dvd_2707946.iso
```

A list with supported values can be queried by

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu "?"
```

**Update**:

Oh yeah, forgot to warn you: It still might not work. QEMU is fine for current Linux versions and “old-ish” Windows versions, but it probably won’t run Windows 8+ without KVM support.